# Added events in google calendar not display in Android Pie?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I want to add events in google calendar programmatically and I have the following code to add events on my calendar:

```
try {
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            String calendarId = getGmailCalendarId(mContext);

            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endMillis);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
            //values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, false);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calendarId);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, Calendar.getInstance()
                    .getTimeZone().getID());

            System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getID());

//            Uri uri;
//            if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 8)
//                uri = cr.insert(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), values);
//            else
//                uri = cr.insert(Uri.parse("content://calendar/events"), values);

            Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
            long eventId = java.lang.Long.parseLong(((Uri) uri).getLastPathSegment());
            Log.d("Event_Id", eventId + "");
            syncCalendar(mContext, calendarId);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I got correct gmail id using this method which returns me calendarId.

**getGmailCalendarId()**

```
public String getGmailCalendarId(Context c) {
        String calenderId = "";
        String[] projection = new String[]{"_id", "calendar_displayName"};
        Uri calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
        ContentResolver contentResolver = c.getContentResolver();
        Cursor managedCursor = contentResolver.query(calendars,
                projection, null, null, null);

        if (managedCursor != null && managedCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            String calName;
            String calID;
            int nameCol = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(projection[1]);
            int idCol = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
            do {
                calName = managedCursor.getString(nameCol);
                calID = managedCursor.getString(idCol);
                if (calName.contains("@gmail")) {
                    calenderId = calID;
                    break;
                }


            } while (managedCursor.moveToNext());
            managedCursor.close();
            return calenderId;
        }

        return calenderId;

    }
```

**syncCalendar**

```
public static void syncCalendar(Context context, String calendarId) {
    try {
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS, 1);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.VISIBLE, 1);

        Uri updateUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(calendarId));
        cr.update(updateUri, values, null, null);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Everything is perfect, There is no any error. It returns me event id which means the event added successfully. **The Issue is**, the added events are visible in google calendar in all devices except **android pie (9)**. In android pie, it returns  me event id but events are not displaying in calendar app.

> The added events are visible in google calendar for all devices except
>   android pie (9)

*I followed many SO questions and answers but never get any idea about android pie issue with calendar.*

Comment: When I'm using your code to add the event it is shown in google calendar with delay. Like 2-3 minutes. Did you have similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

I fought for this issue from many days, but finally I solved it. The issue is with google account in my android pie device.

The steps, I followed are

- Logout all google accounts from the device
- Then Login with all accounts
- Run the app and execute the code.

After that it works fine in my device.